# Devise - could not find valid mapping error while disabling a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Iam trying to disable auser using active_for_authentication? method. 
My problem is whenever i try to signin with a disabled user, the app throws an error .

```
RuntimeError (Could not find a valid mapping for #<User details>
```

user.rb

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

def is_active?
  false
end

def active_for_authentication?
  super && self.is_active?
end
```

Comment: This seems to be a routing issue. Post your `routes.rb` so people can help.

Comment: can you check your mappings settings in application initializer

Comment: @Deep , It is not a routing issue, when is_active returns true, Iam able to login without any problem.

Comment: @Sontya , where can I find the mapping settings ?

Comment: in `config/environments/development.rb` file

Comment: I dont have any mapping settings specified.. 

I only get the error when I disable a user, else, everything is working fine..

Comment: it's just a guess, I am not sure. In the file you can add `env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]`

Comment: It didnt work. :( .   It is a devise issue, some devise module is overriding my devise authentication...